# Checking digital signature programmatically from Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, digital-signature, digital-certificate

I need a function in Delphi to verify the digital signature of an external EXE or DLL.  In my particular application, I am going to occasionally invoke other processes, but for security purposes I want to make sure these executables were created by our organization before running them.

I have seen [Microsoft's example in C](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382384), however, I do not want to waste the time translating this to Delphi if somebody else already has.

I would prefer a snippet or code example over a third-party library.  Thanks.

Comment: You wouldn't really be wasting any time. That code sets the fields of *one* record and calls *one* API function. Everything else is just comments explaining what each of the possible return values means. In short, the way to check the digital signature is to simply call [`WinVerifyTrust`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa388208).

Comment: There are a number of structures and constants used in that example that are not defined in Windows.pas.

Comment: Despite how trivial it may or may not be, every time a Delphi developer wants to do this, they will need to take the time to   research and translate themselves.  Not sure why this was downvoted.

Comment: A lot of Windows API calls and structs are already translated by the Jedi team. That is the second place I look (after a quick google) when I need an API call translated. I'm still on Delphi 7, so there is a lot missing in Windows.pas. [JEDI API Library](http://jedi-apilib.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here you go:

```
// IsCodeSigned, which verifies that the exe hasn't been modified, uses
// WinVerifyTrust, so it's NT only.  IsCompanySigningCertificate works on Win9x, 
// but it only checks that the signing certificate hasn't been replaced, which
// keeps someone from re-signing a modified executable.

// Imagehlp.dll
const
  CERT_SECTION_TYPE_ANY = $FF;      // Any Certificate type

function ImageEnumerateCertificates(FileHandle: THandle; TypeFilter: WORD;
  out CertificateCount: DWORD; Indicies: PDWORD; IndexCount: Integer): BOOL; stdcall; external 'Imagehlp.dll';
function ImageGetCertificateHeader(FileHandle: THandle; CertificateIndex: Integer;
  var CertificateHeader: TWinCertificate): BOOL; stdcall; external 'Imagehlp.dll';
function ImageGetCertificateData(FileHandle: THandle; CertificateIndex: Integer;
  Certificate: PWinCertificate; var RequiredLength: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall; external 'Imagehlp.dll';

// Crypt32.dll
const
  CERT_NAME_SIMPLE_DISPLAY_TYPE = 4;
  PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING = $00010000;
  X509_ASN_ENCODING = $00000001;

type
  PCCERT_CONTEXT = type Pointer;
  HCRYPTPROV_LEGACY = type Pointer;
  PFN_CRYPT_GET_SIGNER_CERTIFICATE = type Pointer;

  CRYPT_VERIFY_MESSAGE_PARA = record
    cbSize: DWORD;
    dwMsgAndCertEncodingType: DWORD;
    hCryptProv: HCRYPTPROV_LEGACY;
    pfnGetSignerCertificate: PFN_CRYPT_GET_SIGNER_CERTIFICATE;
    pvGetArg: Pointer;
  end;

function CryptVerifyMessageSignature(const pVerifyPara: CRYPT_VERIFY_MESSAGE_PARA;
  dwSignerIndex: DWORD; pbSignedBlob: PByte; cbSignedBlob: DWORD; pbDecoded: PBYTE;
  pcbDecoded: PDWORD; ppSignerCert: PCCERT_CONTEXT): BOOL; stdcall; external 'Crypt32.dll';
function CertGetNameStringA(pCertContext: PCCERT_CONTEXT; dwType: DWORD; dwFlags: DWORD; pvTypePara: Pointer;
  pszNameString: PAnsiChar; cchNameString: DWORD): DWORD; stdcall; external 'Crypt32.dll';
function CertFreeCertificateContext(pCertContext: PCCERT_CONTEXT): BOOL; stdcall; external 'Crypt32.dll';
function CertCreateCertificateContext(dwCertEncodingType: DWORD;
  pbCertEncoded: PBYTE; cbCertEncoded: DWORD): PCCERT_CONTEXT; stdcall; external 'Crypt32.dll';

// WinTrust.dll
const
  WINTRUST_ACTION_GENERIC_VERIFY_V2: TGUID = '{00AAC56B-CD44-11d0-8CC2-00C04FC295EE}';
  WTD_CHOICE_FILE = 1;
  WTD_REVOKE_NONE = 0;
  WTD_UI_NONE = 2;

type
  PWinTrustFileInfo = ^TWinTrustFileInfo;
  TWinTrustFileInfo = record
    cbStruct: DWORD;                    // = sizeof(WINTRUST_FILE_INFO)
    pcwszFilePath: PWideChar;           // required, file name to be verified
    hFile: THandle;                     // optional, open handle to pcwszFilePath
    pgKnownSubject: PGUID;              // optional: fill if the subject type is known
  end;

  PWinTrustData = ^TWinTrustData;
  TWinTrustData = record
    cbStruct: DWORD;
    pPolicyCallbackData: Pointer;
    pSIPClientData: Pointer;
    dwUIChoice: DWORD;
    fdwRevocationChecks: DWORD;
    dwUnionChoice: DWORD;
    pFile: PWinTrustFileInfo;
    dwStateAction: DWORD;
    hWVTStateData: THandle;
    pwszURLReference: PWideChar;
    dwProvFlags: DWORD;
    dwUIContext: DWORD;
  end;

function WinVerifyTrust(hwnd: HWND; const ActionID: TGUID; ActionData: Pointer): Longint; stdcall; external wintrust;

{-----------------------------------------------}

function IsCodeSigned(const Filename: string): Boolean;
var 
  file_info: TWinTrustFileInfo;
  trust_data: TWinTrustData;
begin
  // Verify that the exe is signed and the checksum matches
  FillChar(file_info, SizeOf(file_info), 0);
  file_info.cbStruct := sizeof(file_info);
  file_info.pcwszFilePath := PWideChar(WideString(Filename));
  FillChar(trust_data, SizeOf(trust_data), 0);
  trust_data.cbStruct := sizeof(trust_data);
  trust_data.dwUIChoice := WTD_UI_NONE;
  trust_data.fdwRevocationChecks := WTD_REVOKE_NONE;
  trust_data.dwUnionChoice := WTD_CHOICE_FILE;
  trust_data.pFile := @file_info;
  Result := WinVerifyTrust(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, WINTRUST_ACTION_GENERIC_VERIFY_V2,
    @trust_data) = ERROR_SUCCESS
end;

{-----------------------------------------------}

function IsCompanySigningCertificate(const Filename, CompanyName :string): Boolean;
var
  hExe: HMODULE;
  Cert: PWinCertificate;
  CertContext: PCCERT_CONTEXT;
  CertCount: DWORD;
  CertName: AnsiString;
  CertNameLen: DWORD;
  VerifyParams: CRYPT_VERIFY_MESSAGE_PARA;
begin
  // Returns TRUE if the SubjectName on the certificate used to sign the exe is
  // "Company Name".  Should prevent a cracker from modifying the file and
  // re-signing it with their own certificate.
  //
  // Microsoft has an example that does this using CryptQueryObject and
  // CertFindCertificateInStore instead of CryptVerifyMessageSignature, but
  // CryptQueryObject is NT-only.  Using CertCreateCertificateContext doesn't work
  // either, though I don't know why.
  Result := False;
  // Verify that the exe was signed by our private key
  hExe := CreateFile(PChar(Filename), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,
    nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL or FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS, 0);
  if hExe = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
    Exit;
  try
    // There should only be one certificate associated with the exe
    if (not ImageEnumerateCertificates(hExe, CERT_SECTION_TYPE_ANY, CertCount, nil, 0)) or
       (CertCount <> 1) then
      Exit;
    // Read the certificate header so we can get the size needed for the full cert
    GetMem(Cert, SizeOf(TWinCertificate) + 3); // ImageGetCertificateHeader writes an DWORD at bCertificate for some reason
    try
      Cert.dwLength := 0;
      Cert.wRevision := WIN_CERT_REVISION_1_0;
      if not ImageGetCertificateHeader(hExe, 0, Cert^) then
        Exit;
      // Read the full certificate
      ReallocMem(Cert, SizeOf(TWinCertificate) + Cert.dwLength);
      if not ImageGetCertificateData(hExe, 0, Cert, Cert.dwLength) then
        Exit;
      // Get the certificate context.  CryptVerifyMessageSignature has the
      // side effect of creating a context for the signing certificate.
      FillChar(VerifyParams, SizeOf(VerifyParams), 0);
      VerifyParams.cbSize := SizeOf(VerifyParams);
      VerifyParams.dwMsgAndCertEncodingType := X509_ASN_ENCODING or PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING;
      if not CryptVerifyMessageSignature(VerifyParams, 0, @Cert.bCertificate,
         Cert.dwLength, nil, nil, @CertContext) then
        Exit;
      try
        // Extract and compare the certificate's subject names.  Don't
        // compare the entire certificate or the public key as those will
        // change when the certificate is renewed.
        CertNameLen := CertGetNameStringA(CertContext,
          CERT_NAME_SIMPLE_DISPLAY_TYPE, 0, nil, nil, 0);
        SetLength(CertName, CertNameLen - 1);
        CertGetNameStringA(CertContext, CERT_NAME_SIMPLE_DISPLAY_TYPE, 0,
          nil, PAnsiChar(CertName), CertNameLen);
        if CertName <> CompanyName then 
          Exit;
      finally
        CertFreeCertificateContext(CertContext)
      end;
    finally
      FreeMem(Cert);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(hExe);
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this appears to operate on the current executable, rather than an external exe specified by filename.  Sorry, I probably should have been more clear.  Would it be a lot of work to alter this snippet to function in such a way?

Comment: scrapdog: Just replace ParamStr(0) (appears twice) with the name of the file you want to check.

Comment: @scrapdog: Make sure you call both functions if you're running on NT.  IsCompanySigningCertificate works on both 9x and NT, but only verifies that the exe has your certificate on it.  IsCodeSigned actually verifies that file hasn't been tampered with.  I updated IsCodeSigned to take a filename as well.

Comment: Hi, do you have an solution to digitally sign a document from Delphi? I already have a DSC, I use it from Adobe acrobat. https://stackoverflow.com/q/72920389/10975845

Answer (score 3):

```
const
  WTD_UI_ALL    = 1;
  WTD_UI_NONE   = 2;
  WTD_UI_NOBAD  = 3;
  WTD_UI_NOGOOD = 4;

  WTD_REVOKE_NONE       = $00000000;
  WTD_REVOKE_WHOLECHAIN = $00000001;

  WTD_CHOICE_FILE    = 1;
  WTD_CHOICE_CATALOG = 2;
  WTD_CHOICE_BLOB    = 3;
  WTD_CHOICE_SIGNER  = 4;
  WTD_CHOICE_CERT    = 5;

  WTD_STATEACTION_IGNORE           = $00000000;
  WTD_STATEACTION_VERIFY           = $00000001;
  WTD_STATEACTION_CLOSE            = $00000002;
  WTD_STATEACTION_AUTO_CACHE       = $00000003;
  WTD_STATEACTION_AUTO_CACHE_FLUSH = $00000004;

type
  PWinTrustFileInfo = ^TWinTrustFileInfo;
  TWinTrustFileInfo = record
    cbStruct: DWORD;
    pcwszFilePath: PWideChar;
    hFile: THandle;
    pgKnownSubject: PGUID;
  end;

  PWinTrustData = ^TWinTrustData;
  TWinTrustData = record
    cbStruct: DWORD;
    pPolicyCallbackData: Pointer;
    pSIPClientData: Pointer;
    dwUIChoice: DWORD;
    fdwRevocationChecks: DWORD;
    dwUnionChoice: DWORD;
    pUnionData: Pointer;
    dwStateAction: DWORD;
    hWVTStateData: THandle;
    pwszURLReference: PWideChar;
    dwProvFlags: DWORD;
    dwUIContext: DWORD;
  end;

function VerifySignature(const FileName: WideString): Longint;
var
  FileInfo: TWinTrustFileInfo;
  TrustData: TWinTrustData;
begin
  FillChar(FileInfo, SizeOf(FileInfo), 0);
  FileInfo.cbStruct := SizeOf(FileInfo);
  FileInfo.pcwszFilePath := PWideChar(FileName);

  FillChar(TrustData, SizeOf(TrustData), 0);
  TrustData.cbStruct := SizeOf(TrustData);
  TrustData.dwUIChoice := WTD_UI_NONE;
  TrustData.fdwRevocationChecks := WTD_REVOKE_NONE;
  TrustData.dwUnionChoice := WTD_CHOICE_FILE;
  TrustData.pUnionData := @FileInfo;
  TrustData.dwStateAction := WTD_STATEACTION_IGNORE;
  TrustData.dwProvFlags := WTD_SAFER_FLAG;
  TrustData.dwUIContext := WTD_UICONTEXT_EXECUTE;

  Result := WinVerifyTrust(0, WINTRUST_ACTION_GENERIC_VERIFY_V2, @TrustData);
end;
```

There are more details in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa388208).

Alternatively, you can use [CAPICOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375732%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Import the CAPICOM type library from capicom.dll and then use the generated CAPICOM_TLB unit:

```
procedure CodeSignVerify(const FileName: string; AllowUserPrompt: Boolean = False);
var
  SignedCode: ISignedCode;
begin
  SignedCode := CoSignedCode.Create;
  SignedCode.FileName := FileName;
  SignedCode.Verify(AllowUserPrompt);
end;
```

Comment: `WTD_SAFER_FLAG` is \ has been marked as "not supported".

Comment: Is there a simpler way just to check if the file is signed or not ? I don't need the signature details. just know if it's signed.